# Nuance of saying "同い年"? And, it is 当て字?

Tags: nuances, ateji

If saying 同{おな}い年{どし} in daily conversation is just something you'd say without thinking twice, *then I have no further questions.*

But, doesn't saying 同い年 sound sort of stand-offish. Saying 同い年 is a hint to the listener that he is misunderstanding our level of friendship.

My asking question to Empress Michiko at お茶会

> (私): "その二人子、同い年ですか。

This is normal usage.

My sister-in-law asking me a question at お寿司屋さん

> (義理姉さん response #1): "その二人子、年齢が一緒ですか。
>    (義理姉さん response #2): "その二人子、同い年ですか。

I'd expect response #1.
Hearing #2, I'd be like that was completely uncalled for. What is her problem? If she wants to keep her distance, then so be it.

*BTW*:
同い年 **is** considered 当て字, right? I've never seen a word made 当て字 by its 送りがな.

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with 同い年. It's a standard word.

Comment: If you think about it, the only part of 「同{おな}い年{どし}」 that doesn't fit the usual reading (「い」 rather than 「じ」) is written with kana, so I suppose technically the kanji are used normally.  The 常用漢字表 lists it as an example under the reading おなじ without making any kind of special note.

Comment: @strawberryjam Not if it is a "standard" word. For example, while still using "standard" English, I can adjust my vocab and sentence structures to make it clear I don't consider the listener a close friend.

Comment: @konishiki standard word as in no nuance

Comment: @snailboat I just feel that how a word is written in Japanese sometimes communicates meaning up to the nuance of speaking it (but English spelling sure doesn't ex: "Mississippi.) Seeing how "同い年" is written and then the context I learned it in made my ears perk-up. But, I was definitely wrong. thanks.

Comment: 「その二人子」はどういう意味ですか？ Did you mean to write 「その二人は、同い年ですか？」? If talking to Empress Michiko it'd be better to say そちらのお二人は、同い年でいらっしゃいますか？

Comment: I think 同い年 is [イ音便](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%9F%B3%E4%BE%BF#.E3.82.A4.E9.9F.B3.E4.BE.BF) of 同じ年... Sorry if I'm wrong

Comment: 同じ年 is made of two words 同じ and 年.
同い年 is one word. That is a common word.
It seems that it is used by students mainly.
Incidentally, 同じ has various way of speaking. おなし, おんなじ

Comment: @chocolate Without realizing it, most natives want speed from their non-natives. So, I'd thought "二人子" is an ok version of "二人の子ども"??? "二人子" helps stay in rhythm because you get it out with a quick exhale and no lip movement. Native Japanese sounds so wonderful. My Japanese sounds like fingernails of a chalkboard, but I' still trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

同い年 is the sound change of 同じ年(same age). And 同い年 is often used as　同じ学年(same grade in school).

Comment: Would you use 同い年 in a daily conversation? There is no nuance?

Comment: Yes, 同い年 is common but it has often a nuance like "same grade in school" as I answered.